# Potential pitfalls for conditional componants with circular reference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-Zv73yZ_QI) video and thought the approach was really neat. The code i am posting is not shown but can be found in the [repo](https://github.com/tnarla/nextjs-conf/blob/main/src/components/ui/ButtonOrLink.tsx) linked in the comments ([and its useage](https://github.com/tnarla/nextjs-conf/blob/main/src/components/ui/Button.tsx)).
However i was a little confused that the ButtonOrLink component is returning itself. Are there potential pitfalls to doing it this way?

```
import { ComponentProps } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

type ButtonOrLinkProps = ComponentProps<"button"> & ComponentProps<"a">;

export interface Props extends ButtonOrLinkProps {}

export function ButtonOrLink({ href, ...props }: Props) {
    const isLink = typeof href !== "undefined";
    const ButtonOrLink = isLink ? "a" : "button";

    let content = <ButtonOrLink {...props} />;

    if (isLink) <Link href={href}>{content}</Link>;

    return content;
}
```

It works just fine i just need feedback on the potential pitfalls regarding the circular dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't actually a circular dependency. Because of the block scope, the `const ButtonOrLink` declaration overwrites the `function BlockOrLink` declaration. The component rendered to `content` will always be an `<a>` or `<button>`.

To the point of potential pitfalls, there is a refactoring risk or a confusion risk. If the `const ButtonOrLink` were renamed, misspelled, etc. and the `let content = <ButtonOrLink ...` line was not changed, then you would have an endless loop. It would be safer and probably clearer to change those names inside the component. Maybe `ButtonOrA` would be clearer and more accurate. I've often seen people simply use `Component` in this case.

Comment: Thanks that cleared up my confusion. Never seen a string being used to define a tag name that way.